# Would like to create some VBA code that repeats a formula but for the next set of cells needed

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to repeat a sum formula however it would be for the next shifted rows. this is for a large data set that would take significant amount of time if done manually. For instance in cell `E10` i have `=SUM('Raw Data'!D10:D31)`. I would like cell `E12` to be `=SUM('Raw Data'!D42:D63)` and `E14` to be `=SUM('Raw Data'!D74:D95)` and continue. I know the cell is always located 2 rows lower and i know that i always want the area getting summed to be 32 rows lower.

Comment: Create a loop, step by 2, add 32 to your cell references.

Comment: A loop should work, incrementing by 2. Do you have some code you have tried?

Comment: `D10:D31`, `D42:D63` & `D74:D95` is all 22 rows each

Comment: @AsUsual check your math

Comment: @AsUsual They mean between each call, not the difference in range within each call.

Comment: @MilesFett Please explain what part of my comment is wrong

Comment: Could you to give some feedback on the answer I posted? Does it answer your question?  If so, may I ask you to accept my answer [how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Sub sumSomething()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i As Long, x As Long, rws As Long

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E10") 'Starting range of sums
    Set ws = Sheets("Raw Data") 'Sheet from where you want to sum up values

    rws = 32 'Number of rows you want to sum
    x = 2 'Jump between sum formulas

    For i = 1 To Round(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row / rws, 0)
        rng.Offset((i - 1) * x).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM('" & ws.Name & "'!R[" & -(i - 1) * x + rws * (i - 1) & "]C[-1]:R[" & -(i - 1) * x + rws * ((i - 1) + 1) - 1 & "]C[-1])"
    Next i
End Sub
```